# Programmatically toggle Bootstrap 5 collapse component

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I'm using a boostrap 5 "collapse", **using the data attributes approach**. It works as expected. I can click the button to collapse/expand the collapsible items.

The [docs state](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/collapse/#methods) I can toggle the state manually, like so:

```js
let element = document.querySelector('#my-collapse');
bootstrap.Collapse.getInstance(element).toggle();
```

However that fails, as `getInstance` returns `null`.

Strangely, if I click the collapse button, then use that code, it works.

How do I ensure the code works without first "priming" the collapse component?

Comment: Try to select the element using an `id` instead of using the `collapse` class. E.g.: `document.querySelector('#my-collapse-element');`

Comment: @DimitrisMaragkos Thanks! That isn't the problem though, I can find the element without problem (`element` is not null), but `getInstance` returns null. Also that code works as is, once I manually click the collapse button. Weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think when using data attributes, the bootstrap component is only created on demand - i.e. when the collapse button is clicked for the first time. That would explain the behaviour I've noted above.

So the solution is to use `getOrCreateInstance` instead:

```js
let element = document.querySelector('#my-collapse');
bootstrap.Collapse.getOrCreateInstance(element).toggle();
```

Answer (score 2):

The code below insures that collapse instance is not null:

```
let element = document.querySelector('#my-collapse');
// try to get collapse instance
let bsCollapse = bootstrap.Collapse.getInstance(element);
// if the instance is not yet initialized then create new collapse
if (bsCollapse === null) {
    bsCollapse = new bootstrap.Collapse(element, {
        toggle: false   // this parameter is important!
    })
}
bsCollapse.show();
```

Comment: Thanks. However this is unnecessarily complex - `getOrCreateInstance` does all that in one line. Its return value could only be null if the selector is invalid, in which case you have bigger problems (and the question relates to creating the component via data attributes, which means you already have a valid selector.)

Comment: @lonix - you would think `getOrCreateInstance` is enough, but it wasn't in my case.
This `bootstrap.Collapse.getOrCreateInstance('#my-collapse').show();` would collapse already open Collapsable instead of showing it user did not interact with the collapsable yet. The only solution for me is the code above.

Comment: If you think it's a bug, I suggest you open an issue on the repo, and ping me with a link so I can upvote it.

Comment: This was also the case for me. `getOrCreateInstance` was closing the collapse menu instead of leaving it open, which caused issues in my code, because I was expecting to either fire the `shown.bs.collapse` event or run `my_instance.show()`, depending on whether it was open or not. Thank you for this gem; hopefully this was fixed in v 5.3.